# Sagt man bei Vögeln auch "Geburt"?

Tags: single-word-request

Man kann sagen, eine Katze habe *von Geburt an* bei Menschen gelebt. Aber kann man auch von Vögeln sagen, sie seien irgendwas "von Geburt an"?

Vögel werden ja nicht geboren, sondern schlüpfen. Das entsprechende Substantiv finde ich zwar [im Wörterbuch](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schlupf) ("der Schlupf eines Kükens aus dem Ei"), das Wort kommt mir aber doch recht befremdlich vor.

Wie sagt das der Nicht-Zoologe?

---

*Beispiele*

> Der Vogel ist von Geburt an blind.
>   Der Vogel ist von Schlupf an blind.

Beides klingt für mich falsch.

Comment: Es gibt noch eine andere Substantivierung: _das Schlüpfen_. Wäre das keine Option?

Comment: @Marzipanherz So isset - "Direkt nach dem Schlüpfen ist der Jungvogel noch blind. " - *Geburt* geht überhaupt nicht, *Schlupf* eher auch nicht (das ist besetzt durch den Begriff aus der Mechanik, das Durchrutschen von Maschinenelementen)

Comment: @tofro erstaunlicher Weise scheint es aber keinen eigenen Eintrag im Duden oder DWDS zu haben. Aber bei [canoo.net](http://canoo.net/inflection/schl%C3%BCpfen:N:N) habe ich es gefunden

Comment: @Marzipanherz In den Wörterbüchern dürften die meisten substantivierten Verben nicht extra aufgeführt sein.

Comment: @tofro: Schlupf hat eine dauerhafte, durch einen Geschwindigkeitsunterschied gekennzeichnete, dennoch kraftschlüssige Verbindung.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Auch ich habe bei "Schlupf" zuerst an das Durchrutschen von Machinenelementen gedacht. Für alle, die mit Technik zu tun haben, ist das wahrscheinlich der erste Gedanke. "Das Schlüpfen" ist aber eine gute Möglichkeit. Willst du das nicht als Antwort schreiben?

Comment: Ich sehe nicht ein, warum man im Kontext der Ornithologie (und bei anderen Eierlegern) nicht von *Schlupf* reden sollte. Dass Ingenieure unter *Schlupf* was anderes verstehen, ist durchaus kein Hinderungsgrund. Ingenieure verstehen auch unter *Mutter* etwas anderes. Ja und?

Comment: @Walze erledigt :)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich spreche und schreibe aber nicht im Kontext der Ornithologie. Ich will im Alltag keine Fachsprache verwenden, die meine Gesprächspartner nicht verstehen.

Comment: @Walze  Dann, liebe Walze, solltest du in der Tat *Schlupf* fürs Vogelschlüpfen nicht verwenden. Es ist ja nicht mal unter Ornithologen gebräuchlich. Ich habe nur dafür plädiert, es in diesen Kontext als scnönes, kurzes, klares Wort einzuführen.

Comment: Werden eigentlich Schnabeltiere und Ameisenigel als Säugetiere geboren oder nicht?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In diesem Fall baut man den Satz anders:

> Der Vogel ist blind, seit er aus dem Ei geschlüpft ist.

Dieser Satz ist fachlich falsch:

> Der Vogel ist von Geburt an blind.

Dieser mag vielleicht in einem fachsprachlichen Kontext akzeptabel sein, in einem anderen Kontext ruft er aber Verwirrung hervor:

> Der Vogel ist von Schlupf an blind.

Beide letztgenannten Sätze sind grammatisch aber natürlich vollkommen korrekt.

Comment: "Der Vogel ist von Schlupf an blind" ist zwar - finde ich - lexikologisch elegant, jedoch ist er faktologisch problemamtisch: Der Vogel ist nämlich auch schon blind, solange er noch ruhig im Ei sitzt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann So grundsätzlich hast Di ja recht, aber macht man das bei Menschen nicht auch so? _Peter war von Geburt an blind._ - auch wenn er es vermutlich schon pränatal war. ..

Comment: @Marzipanherz Mir geht es da wie Christian Geiselmann, nur habe ich den Kommentar gestern Abend unterlassen. Auch ich denke bei "von Schlupf an", dass der Küken im Ei noch gesehen haben könne, während ich das bei "von Geburt an" nicht so empfinde. Irgendwie hat "von Geburt an" eben doch die Bedeutung "von Anfang an" während man das Schlüpfen nicht als Anfang begreift.

Comment: Hubert, das finde ich eine gut Lösung, würde allerdings schreiben (nicht sagen): `Der Vogel ist, seit er geschlüpft ist, blind.` Fühlt sich eleganter an für mich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es überhaupt Vögel gibt, die nach dem Schlüpfen sehen können. Wenn ich mir alle Bilder von frisch geschlüpften Vögeln ins Gedächtnis rufe, dann kann ich mich nicht an ein einziges Bild erinnern, wo die frisch geschlüpften Jungtiere die Augen offen haben. Ich glaube kein Vogel kann unmittelbar nach dem Schlüpfen sehen. Soweit ich weiß, dauert das immer mehrere Tage bis Wochen, bis sie ihre Augen so weit entwickelt sind, dass sie sie öffnen und benutzen können. Wenn ich recht habe, sind alle frisch geschlüpften Vögel blind, und daher auch davor.

Answer (score 5):

Wie schon kommentiert, würde ich *das Schlüpfen* vorschlagen - eine Substantivierung des Verbs *schlüpfen*. Deinen Beispielsatz könnte man damit folgendermaßen formulieren:

> Der Vogel ist seit dem Schlüpfen blind.

Ich hatte noch versucht, den entsprechenden Eintrag in einigen gängigen Nachschlagewerken zu finden.

Es gibt einen Eintrag bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/schl%C3%BCpfen:N:N), allerdings keinen beim [Duden](https://www.duden.de/). Auch beim [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de) bin ich nicht fündig geworden.

Wie User [tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20363/tofro) im Kommentar oben richtig schrieb, werden viele substantivierte Verben in solchen Nachschlagewerken nicht gesondert aufgeführt. Ich hatte gehofft, dass *Schlüpfen* eine Ausnahme sein könnte, weil es mir sehr geläufig ist (im Gegensatz zu *Schlupf*, das kannte ich vorher nur aus Zusammensetzungen wie *Unterschlupf*, *Schlupfloch* oder *Schlupflid*).

Ich kann also nicht ausschließen, dass *Schlüpfen* z.B. regional unterschiedlich häufig gebraucht wird.

Answer (score 1):

Deine beiden Beispiele klingen merkwürdig, weil sie so nicht üblich sind; wer nicht auffallen will, packt die Botschaft in einen Standardsatz. Einer wurde ja bereits genannt.

> - Der Vogel ist blind geschlüpft.
> - Der Vogel ist blind, seit es ihn gibt.
> - Der Vogel ist von Anfang an blind.
> - Der Vogel ist blind seit Stunde null.

Falsch sind deine Beispiele aber nicht. Das zweite ohnehin nicht, das erste deshalb nicht:

Die Verwendung von »Geburt« setzt keine Gebärmutter voraus; so spricht der Duden beispielsweise von »Zur-Welt-Kommen« ([Bedeutung 1b](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Geburt#Bedeutung1b)). Der Mensch beginnt sein Leben, wenn der letzte Fuß draußen ist – der Vogel auch. Das ist die Geburt. Abgesehen davon lässt sich die Gebärmutter als inneres Ei verstehen.

Der Einsatz von »Geburt« geht aber noch weiter, ist noch nicht einmal an Lebewesen geknüpft, denn es gibt auch den metaphorischen Gebrauch.

> - Das Verschwinden der Fuhrwerke begann mit der Geburt des Automobils.
> - Die Geburt der Musik aus dem Schrei

Wenn etwas aus dem Schrei geboren werden kann, dann auch aus dem Ei.

Comment: So rein sprachlich bin ich da mit Dir, außer bei dem Satz mit der Gebärmutter als innerem Ei, da geht der Biologe in mir auf die Barrikade. Auch wenn ich weiß, was Du meinst.

Comment: Ich sehe das ähnlich. Vor allem war auch explizit nach der Wendung _von Geburt an_ gefragt, bei der stabilitätsbedingt noch größerer Abstand zum Gebärvorgang herrschen dürfte. (_ab ovo_ weist, nur nebenbei bemerkt, auch ein breites Verwendungsspektrum auf, das nicht auf Schlüpfvorgänge beschränkt ist.)

Comment: Nun ja. Richtig ist, dass metaphorische Formen sehr frei verwendet werden können. Wenn aber eine Verwechslungsgefahr mit der unmittelbaren Bedeutung besteht, sollte man keine Metaphern verwenden. Beispiel: Hetzjagd.